# Apply median on image with multiple threads

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, image-processing, bufferedimage

For a school assignment we have to apply a median filter to a noisy PNG image. 
I have the following:

```
public static void main(String[] a) throws Throwable {
    final String extension = "png";
    final String input = "input1.png";
    final String output = "output1.png";

    final int threadsAmount = 4;

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final Image image = new Image(input, output, extension);

    image.applyMedian(threadsAmount);
    long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    System.out.println("duration: " + duration);
}
```

A method to apply a median filter to the image, creating a buffered image, reading it out, calculating the averages and putting them in an new bufferedImage which is exported to a new image.

```
public void applyMedian(int threadAmount) throws IOException, Exception {
    File imageFile = new File(this.input);
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imageFile);

    int imageHeight = bufferedImage.getHeight();
    int imageWidth = bufferedImage.getWidth();

    BufferedImage finalImage = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, bufferedImage.getType());
    int heightPerThread = imageHeight / threadAmount;
    Color[] surroundedPixel = new Color[9];
    int[] R = new int[9];
    int[] B = new int[9];
    int[] G = new int[9];

    for (int j = 1; j < bufferedImage.getHeight() - 1; j++) {
        for (int i = 1; i < bufferedImage.getWidth() - 1; i++) {
            surroundedPixel[0] = new Color(bufferedImage.getRGB(i - 1, j - 1));
            surroundedPixel[1] = new Color(bufferedImage.getRGB(i - 1, j));
            surroundedPixel[2] = new Color(bufferedImage.getRGB(i - 1, j + 1));
            surroundedPixel[3] = new Color(bufferedImage.getRGB(i, j + 1));
            surroundedPixel[4] = new Color(bufferedImage.getRGB(i + 1, j + 1));
            surroundedPixel[5] = new Color(bufferedImage.getRGB(i + 1, j));
            surroundedPixel[6] = new Color(bufferedImage.getRGB(i + 1, j - 1));
            surroundedPixel[7] = new Color(bufferedImage.getRGB(i, j - 1));
            surroundedPixel[8] = new Color(bufferedImage.getRGB(i, j));
            for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++) {
                R[k] = surroundedPixel[k].getRed();
                B[k] = surroundedPixel[k].getBlue();
                G[k] = surroundedPixel[k].getGreen();
            }
            Arrays.sort(R);
            Arrays.sort(G);
            Arrays.sort(B);
            finalImage.setRGB(i, j, new Color(R[4], B[4], G[4]).getRGB());
        }
    }
    ImageIO.write(finalImage, this.getExtension(), new File(this.output));
}
```

In our main, we have an integer which defines the amount of threads we have. Our idea and assignment is that we split the heigt of the whole image in parts and let multiple threads calculate our median.

```
int heightPerThread = imageHeight / threadAmount;
```

However, we've learned how to create threads, but we simply don't know how to apply all those threads on the method above and let all thread handle their own part of the image.

Hope someone could help.

Comment: Using different threads for a single image does not sounds good

Comment: I know right, but for a school assignment it's really important

Comment: @javafan, the purpose behind a school assignment is not to create a commercial grade piece of software, but rather to practice putting to use ideas learned in the classroom.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would require you to add an additional function that you can call from `applyMedian`. The additional function can take the top left corner pixel position `(i, j)` and the height and width the thread should process. You can make it look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] a) throws Throwable {
    final String extension = "png";
    final String input = "input1.png";
    final String output = "output1.png";

    final int threadsAmount = 4;

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final Image image = new Image(input, output, extension);

    image.applyMedian(threadsAmount);
    long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    System.out.println("duration: " + duration);
}
```

And your `applyMedian` should be modified as:

```
public void applyMedian(int threadAmount) throws IOException, Exception {
    File imageFile = new File(this.input);
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imageFile);

    int imageHeight = bufferedImage.getHeight();
    int imageWidth = bufferedImage.getWidth();

    int heightPerThread = imageHeight / threadAmount;
    int widthPerThread = imageWidth / threadAmount

    BufferedImage finalImage = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, bufferedImage.getType());

    // create threads here
    // make all threads invoke the new function here
}
```

And your new function should take the finalImage object, top left corner positions, heightPerThread and widthPerThread as arguments and do the processing you're now doing in applyMedian itself.

```
public newFunction(Image finalImage, int i, int j, int heightPerThread, int widthPerThread) {
    // do all processing here
    // call finalImage.setRGB
}
```

Hope this helps !